# Using a formula on filtered data in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a custom furmula in MS Excel that does some calculations.  I want to perform this formula only on rows that are visible after performing some filters.  I read about SUBTOTAL, but that seems to only work on predefined functions.

So if I have

```
 =SUM(LEN(A1:A10)-LEN(B1:B10))
```

Then I want to perform that only on filtered data.

Comment: I want to perform my own formula only on the rows that are visible from my filter.  So if I have 10 rows, but only 4 after using my filter, my formula I wrote only works on those 4 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `A1:A10` will always be populated try this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:A10)-LEN(B1:B10),SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(A1,ROW(A1:A10)-ROW(A1),0)))`

The `SUBTOTAL/OFFSET` part returns 1 or 0 for each row depending on whether it's visible or not